# How to change a R numeric data frame into a data frame of ordered factors?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 77 numeric variables which are technically ordered factor variables.
I know that I can do the below for changing the first column of data frame `df` into an ordered factor variable:

```
df[,1]<-as.ordered(df[,1])
```

But is there a quick way that I can turn the entire data frame of 77 variables into a data frame of ordered factor variables?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We  can loop over the dataset columns with `lapply`, apply the function and assign it back to the original dataset

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.ordered)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
         mutate_all(as.ordered)
```

Answer (score 1):

For such cases is for loop good and fast enough.

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) df[, i] <- as.factor(df[, i])
```

(Very likely - from my experience - faster than any `lapply` or any `apply`-family solution - because avoiding building lists which are very slow in R.)

For `1:ncol(df)` you can also use `seq_along(df)`.